# Why is my background video only appearing behind one element on my website and not the full screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a background video behind content on my website. I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS and currently practicing by creating a website. I have three columns containing links, together with an animation on each column. I'm trying to put the background vid behind these however it has only worked on one of the columns/elements.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: boldye;
    src: url(/Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/Boldye-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: helvetica;
    src: url(Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/helvetica.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Std;
    src: url(Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/helvetica-Neue-LT.ttf);
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background: #1D1F1A;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: boldye;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

/* Background Vid */
.video-container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}


.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

/* Links */
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.background-one {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.background-two {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.background-three {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.link-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

a {
    font-family: "helvetica Neue LT Std";
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-one {
    color: #ff7340;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
    line-height: 1em;
}

.link-one:hover {
    color: #111;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1);
}

.link-one::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ff7340;

    clip-path: circle(0% at 50% calc(50%));
    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
}

.link-one:hover::before {
    clip-path: circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}

.link-one::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #151515;

    clip-path: polygon(40% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            40% 0%,
            40% 100%,
            60% 100%,
            60% 100%,
            40% 100%);

    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
}

.link-one:hover::after {
    clip-path: polygon(40% 10%,
            60% 10%,
            60% 35%,
            40% 35%,
            40% 90%,
            60% 90%,
            60% 65%,
            40% 65%);
}

.link-two {
    color: #ff7340;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
}

.link-two:hover {
    color: #111;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1);
}

.link-two::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0% -20%,
            100% -30%,
            100% -10%,
            0% 0%,
            0% 130%,
            100% 120%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 110%);
    background-color: #ff7340;

    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.link-two:hover::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 10%,
            100% 0%,
            100% 20%,
            0% 30%,
            0% 100%,
            100% 90%,
            100% 70%,
            0% 80%);
}

.link-two::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 5ch;
    height: 5ch;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;

    background-color: #f27b9b;
}

.link-two:hover::after {
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(135deg) scale(1);
}

.link-three {
    color: #ff7340;
}

.link-three::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;

    clip-path: polygon(20% 60%,
            100% 60%,
            100% 40%,
            20% 40%,
            20% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            60% 20%,
            20% 20%);

    background-color: #eb7132;
}

.link-three:hover::after {
    transform: translate(0, 0%) scaleY(1);
}

.link-three::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    transform: translate(0, 50%) scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;

    clip-path: polygon(80% 40%,
            0% 40%,
            0% 60%,
            80% 60%,
            80% 100%,
            40% 100%,
            40% 80%,
            80% 80%);

    background-color: #eb7132;
}

.link-three:hover::before {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>HAZED Media Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1dabd977a6.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
/>
  </head>
  <body>
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="home.html" id="navbar__logo">hazed</a>
</nav>

<!--Background Vid-->
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="images/showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
<!--Links-->
<div class="background-one">
  <div class="link-container">
    <a
      class="link-one"
      href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
      >SHOWREEL</a
    >
  </div>
</div>
<div class="background-two link-container">
  <a
    class="link-two"
    href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
    >ABOUT US</a
  >
</div>
<div class="background-three link-container">
  <a
    class="link-three"
    href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
    >CONTACT US</a
  >
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried playing around with positions, as well as changing the z-index however can't figure it out. Let me know if sending a screenshot of the website would help.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code like below. Now background video is working fullscreen. I made `link-container div` seperate for each section. I hope it works for you.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: boldye;
    src: url(/Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/Boldye-Regular.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: helvetica;
    src: url(Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/helvetica.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Std;
    src: url(Users/ellie/Libary/Fonts/helvetica-Neue-LT.ttf);
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background: #1D1F1A;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: boldye;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

/* Background Vid */
.video-container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    
}


.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    
}

/* Links */
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.background-one {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.background-two {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.background-three {
    background-color: #1D1F1A;
}

.link-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

a {
    font-family: "helvetica Neue LT Std";
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-one {
    color: #ff7340;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
    line-height: 1em;
    
}

.link-one:hover {
    color: #111;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1);
}

.link-one::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ff7340;

    clip-path: circle(0% at 50% calc(50%));
    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
}

.link-one:hover::before {
    clip-path: circle(100% at 50% 50%);
}

.link-one::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #151515;

    clip-path: polygon(40% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            40% 0%,
            40% 100%,
            60% 100%,
            60% 100%,
            40% 100%);

    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
}

.link-one:hover::after {
    clip-path: polygon(40% 10%,
            60% 10%,
            60% 35%,
            40% 35%,
            40% 90%,
            60% 90%,
            60% 65%,
            40% 65%);
}

.link-two {
    color: #ff7340;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0, 0.67, 0);
}

.link-two:hover {
    color: #111;
    transition: color 1s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1);
}

.link-two::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0% -20%,
            100% -30%,
            100% -10%,
            0% 0%,
            0% 130%,
            100% 120%,
            100% 100%,
            0% 110%);
    background-color: #ff7340;

    transition: clip-path 1s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.link-two:hover::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 10%,
            100% 0%,
            100% 20%,
            0% 30%,
            0% 100%,
            100% 90%,
            100% 70%,
            0% 80%);
}

.link-two::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -3;
    width: 5ch;
    height: 5ch;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;

    background-color: #f27b9b;
}

.link-two:hover::after {
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(135deg) scale(1);
}

.link-three {
    color: #ff7340;
}

.link-three::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;

    clip-path: polygon(20% 60%,
            100% 60%,
            100% 40%,
            20% 40%,
            20% 0%,
            60% 0%,
            60% 20%,
            20% 20%);

    background-color: #eb7132;
}

.link-three:hover::after {
    transform: translate(0, 0%) scaleY(1);
}

.link-three::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    transform: translate(0, 50%) scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;

    clip-path: polygon(80% 40%,
            0% 40%,
            0% 60%,
            80% 60%,
            80% 100%,
            40% 100%,
            40% 80%,
            80% 80%);

    background-color: #eb7132;
}

.link-three:hover::before {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>HAZED Media Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1dabd977a6.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
/>
  </head>
  <body>
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="home.html" id="navbar__logo">hazed</a>
</nav>

<!--Background Vid-->
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://www.ruyatabirleriniz.com/showreel.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
<!--Links-->
<div class="background-one">
  <div class="link-container">
    <a
      class="link-one"
      href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
      >SHOWREEL</a
    >
  </div>
</div>
<div class="background-two">
    <div class="link-container">
  <a
    class="link-two"
    href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
    >ABOUT US</a
  >
</div>
</div>
<div class="background-three">
    <div class="link-container">
  <a
    class="link-three"
    href="https://jhancock532.github.io/link-hover-effects/"
    >CONTACT US</a
  >
</div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```